# jqGrid - Is there a way to check which grouping an item is dropped on?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid with grouping:true and the jQueryUI drag and drop support. When I drag a row from another grid to the grouped grid, I need to know which group the row was dropped on. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible to get Id of that row, you just need to implement your logic like this..

```
jQuery("#gridid").jqGrid({
...
   onSelectRow: function(id){ 
      alert(id); 
   },
...
});
```

try this [here click](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents)

Comment: How can I use that to get the group it was dropped on?